# Getting multiple highest values using Cell Statistics in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, cell-statistics

On my ArcGIS Pro, I have raster data of temperature of each month (from Jan to Dec) in US. Now I want to find out four warmest months, and I think I can use cell statistics tool. How can I do this calculation or is there other tool I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`RasterToNumPyArray`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm) to convert your rasters to numpy arrays and then use Numpy to extract statistics from the arrays. In this example, I extract the median value from each of the 12 arrays, add them to a dictionary, and pick out the top 4 items using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

# Generate some sample numpy array data
datadict = {}
months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"]

for m in months:
    datadict[m] = np.random.randint(255, size=(4, 4))

# Generate a dict with variable name key and median value
d = {k:np.median(v) for k,v in datadict.items()}

# Returns the top 4 items in dict
vals = Counter(d).most_common(4) 
print(vals)
```

---

```
[('oct', 169.0), ('jun', 158.5), ('mar', 134.5), ('apr', 134.0)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!